# Activities search box not automatically selected when pressing Super Key

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I've had this really annoying bug for the last few days: when I press the Super key and type, the input appears in the window I was working prior to launching the Activities overview (i.e. not in the "Type to search" box). However, the search box works correctly when I access the Activities overview via the hot corner.

Is this a known Gnome or Ubuntu 20.04 bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: works absolutely fine on my 20.04.2 LTS Have you set the Super key to something else in keyboard shortcuts perhaps?

Comment: Do you have any gnome shell extensions installed? One of these could cause the issue.

Comment: The issue was fixed on my last reboot. For the record, I had installed the following extensions: Activities Configurator, Clipboard Indicator, Dash to Dock, Freon, GSConnect, Unite, User Themes and Workspace Matrix.